# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have a Spring 3 / Tomcat7 / Servlet 2.4 application that includes a jsp servlet.  The application builds and runs on Eclipse / Tomcat, but fails when deployed on a stand alone server.  The Exception is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.<init>(Validator.java:515)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1817)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
```

So far, I have established that "AbstractMethodError" indicates possible incompatibilities between compiled and deployed versions of a method(?).

Also, I am including jstl version 1.1.2 in the pom - I am wondering if something is going on here with org.apache.jasper.compiler and compatability with Tomcat?

javax.servlet.ServletContext in included in the jstl jar however if I exclude this in the pom the exception still persists

I am building with Java 1.7 and running with the same.

Any help appreciated.....

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. problem solved and recorded here if others may stray this way.
The application is being run on a Tomcat test server with is running multiple applications.  It turns out that there is a conflict between some of the jars in another application and this one - very likely the Vaadin jars.  Either application will run separately, but not on the same instance of Tomcat.  I guess this is a good reason to only run a single application in a tomcat instance...

Comment: Please Can you share with me the solution